# How to filter in openlayer based on Attribute rather than property

Tags: filter, openlayers, rule

I am trying to implement open layer rules and using comparison filtering. However I want to filter based on attributes that I have adeed as extended attributes, rather than property. Does it mean the property and attributes the same?

I would appreciate if someone could clarify that for me.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve but this page covers replacement syntax and custom rules: http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html

Comment: thanks a lot I have ended up using rules and it works like a charm. Many thanks